# What is $G/Z(G)$ in case of $G$ is the group of quaternions?

Tags: quotient-spaces, quaternions, quotient-group, quotient-set

What is $G/Z(G)$ in case of $G$ is the group of quaternions?where $Z(G)$ is the center of $G,$ which is $\{\pm 1\}$

**my guess**

They are the cosets $i + Z(G),j + Z(G), k + Z(G), (-i) + Z(G),(-j) + Z(G), (-k) + Z(G).$ Am I correct?

Comment: No. For starters, by Lagrange's Theorem: $|G/Z(G)|=|G|/|Z(G)|=8/2=4$, so there are only $4$ cosets. Second, the group operation is multiplication, not addition.

Comment: so what are those 4 cosets? @player3236

Comment: $Z(G), iZ(G), jZ(G), kZ(G)$; note that $i$ and $-i$ (e.g.) are in the same coset